# How to maintain radio button and checkboxes after rotation

Tags: java, android

The way I do this is to store selected radio button and checkboxes into their respective variables like I did in onSaveInstanceState(), but I'm stuck at onRestoreInstanceState(). I'm trying to programmatically check the radio button and checkboxes in onRestoreInstanceState(). Is there any easy way to maintain radio button and checkboxes after rotation? Or am I on the right track?

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        //Get the selected radio button and store it in outState
        int radioID = rg_Cooked.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radiobutton = findViewById(radioID);
        outState.putString("selectedRadioButton", radiobutton.getText().toString());

        //Store the selected checkboxes in outState. aListOfAddOns is an array list
        outState.putStringArrayList("selectedCheckboxes", aListOfAddOns);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ***prevent activity from being destroyed on rotation*** by adding this code on the activity tag inside your Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This stops the activity from being recreated during configuration changes.

However the best approach is using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)